Given the function $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, how can I find the $n$-th derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x = 0$, i.e., $f^{(n)}(0)$?
Given the function $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, how can I find  $f^{(n)}(0)$?
The Taylor series for $e^{-x^2}$ can be written by expanding $e^u$ where $u = -x^2$:
$$
e^{-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}
$$
This simplifies to:
$$
e^{-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!}
$$
First of all, why can I simply plug in that $-x^2$
and can I just diffrentiate it? but in order to diffrentiate it term by term I need the sum to converge uniformly to my function. Is it tho? I am not really sure what should I do.
Any help will be appreciated!

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials

Note that the $n^{th}$ term in the power series is equal to $f^{n}(0)/n!$.  This will imply that the odd derivatives are zero and the even ones are given through that expression.

One reason you can simply plug $-x^2$ into the function and differentiate term by term is that both $e^x$ and $-x^2$ are entire functions. So $e^{-x^2}$ is entire and therefore that sort of differentiation is allowed.

Write your series as $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{(2n)!}}{{n!}} \cdot \frac{{x^{2n} }}{{(2n)!}}} $ and compare term-by-term with $
\sum_{k = 0}^\infty  {f^{(k)} (0)\frac{{x^k }}{{k!}}} $.

Power series may be differentiated term-ty-term everywhere strictly inside the radius of convergence.  [Proof hint: comparison to geometric series.] In this case, the radius of convergence id $\infty$.

$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(2k)}(0)}{(2k)!} x^{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(2k+1)}(0)}{(2k+1)!} x^{2k+1}
$$
Now, why can I compare this and simply get equality is that because  $$
{1, x, x^2, x^3, \dots}
$$ is linearly independent?
